# In Gtk, how do I remove the shadow from a Statusbar?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

If I make a `Statusbar`, and `PackEnd` a `Label` to it, it looks something like this:

[image]

The Shadow disappears over the `Label`, but remains over the rest of the `Statusbar`. I want to remove the Shadow from the entire `Statusbar`. The [PyGTK documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkstatusbar.html) mentions a property called `shadow-type`, but it's readonly, and nowhere to be found in GTK#. How do I get rid of this shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to pack stuff into the statusbar, it's not meant as a general container.

To display text in a status bar, use its own API, i.e. [gtk_statusbar_push()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkStatusbar.html#gtk-statusbar-push) from C. The [GTK# docs](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?tlink=root:/classlib-gnome) on go-mono.com seem to be offline, so I couldn't link to those right now.

Answer (score 2):

`shadow-type` is a style property, which means it's actually supposed to be set by the user and/or desktop theme. You can set it by writing a custom style file for your application and reading it in using [`gtk.RcStyle`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkrcstyle.html).

If you have a need for two separate status messages in your application, you could also consider packing two status bars into an hbox.

Answer (score 2):

The first child of a GtkStatusbar is a GtkFrame which gives the shadow border (**edit:** apparently not). You should be able to do this:

```
statusbar.get_children()[0].set_shadow_type(gtk.SHADOW_NONE)
```

Several apps (most notably Epiphany and, in the past, Galeon) actually replace the contents of that frame with an HBox so they can add stuff to the statusbar.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The first child of Statusbar is a Frame, and you can set its shadow type, but the line above the statusbar remains. It must be something other than a shadow.